# How to get class field identifier as String in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

Suppose simple Groovy class (POGO):

```
class Person { String name; int age }
```

How to get chosen identifier at runtime? In other words identifier name (like "name" and "age") used in source code by programmer - not value held in variable of this identifier (like "James" and "32").

With result solution (if there is any) it would be possible to write something like this (syntactically wrong pseudo code):

```
assert new Person().name.identifierAsString == 'name'
assert new Person().age.identifierAsString == 'age'
```

Please note I'm not trying to get *list of field names* (like `Person.declaredFields`), but compile-time safe way to get *field identifier as String*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [wrote a lib](https://github.com/will-lp/latitude) sometime ago to write type-checked queries. It might be what you are after:

```
import org.latitude.Latitude

Customer customer = Latitude.forClass Customer
assert customer instanceof Customer
assert customer.name == "name"
```

Comment: I know that I don't have "thx" but thanks! This library is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish, but you can get all of the declared field names like so:

```
assert ['name', 'age'] == Person.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collect { it.name }
```

And otherwise `declaredFields` is a list of `java.lang.reflect.Field` that you can use.